# ORring input with ' '

Tags: angularjs

I saw the following line in an angular js filter. What does it do?

input = input || ' ';

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: is it to remove whitespace in input?

Comment: this is a logical "OR" - so I'd guess it makes sure that `input` is either the input given, or if that input given is NULL, it makes input at least `string.Empty` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a commonly used construct in javascript to have a default value for an unspecified argument in a function.

This is equivalent to:

```
if (!input) {
    input = ' ';
}
```

Or

```
input = input ? input : ' ';
```

Or more verbose:

```
if (input === null || input === undefined || input === 0 || input === "" || input === false) {
    input = ' ';
}
```

So in this case it assigns a space in case `input` is an empty string or not defined/specified.

Answer (score 0):

In Angularjs, this syntaxe is checking if the input is null. If `input` is null, the value will be `` else it will be `input`.

This syntaxe can avoid `null` or `undefined` value.

Example from angular doc (probably the example in which you see this syntax) :

```
angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(input, uppercase) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      out = input.charAt(i) + out;
    }
    // conditional based on optional argument
    if (uppercase) {
      out = out.toUpperCase();
    }
    return out;
  };
})
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
}]);
```

It's basically put an empty string instead of a `null` value and avoid null if you don't type anything in the example program.

Comment: thanks for the answer.                                                                                    I saw the earlier post first which is why I marked it :)